# ADFS 2.0 CRM Dynamics and SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-2013, adfs2.0

Our current setup:

ADFS 2.0 with rules for CRM Dynamics (works fine), and rules for SharePoint (created from using instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx)

ADFS 2.0 is on the same server as the CRM Dynamics web application - no rewrites or redirects required

SharePoint 2013 is on its own back-end server accessible with appropriate urls defined in DNS. On the ADFS 2.0/CRM Dynamics WFE server, at server-level in IIS, a rewrite rule exists.

> Requested URL Matches the Pattern, using Wildcards. Pattern: *
>
> Conditions: {HOST_HEADER} Matches the pattern: *sharepoint.macreportmedia.com*
>
> Action: Rewrite url: <'url to the sharepoint server'> and append query string
>
> > We've also tried rewrites with {REQUEST_URI} appended along with append query string option checked/unchecked
>
> It's set to NOT stop processing

Our issue:

1. Navigating to our sharepoint URL returns the ADFS 2.0 login page as expected
2. Credentials are authenticated (I can verify this by immediately going to our CRM url and am able to enter the site without authenticating again)
3. Instead of being directed to the sharepoint website, it puts us back to the ADFS 2.0 login page.

If I need to give more information, let me know. We just really need help figuring out WHY we can't get into our Sharepoint page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you experience kind of a redirect loop and that you are using IE.

This is usually happening when the participating sites are not in the same security zone of IE. Therefore they are not able to share the cookies. ADFS sees that your are authenticated and redirects to SharePoint. SharePoint does not receive the tokens and redirects back to ADFS.